# Spinner dropdown drawing top of screen in listview after selecting item

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I'm wondering why having a ListView's layout_height="wrap_content" messes up Spinners at the end of the list.  I ran through different ways of fixing it below.  I'm hoping someone can explain the behaviour, or point out what android knowledge i'm lacking about drawing of views / ui events.

1)  The problem visually can be seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_ep7Si7E6k&feature=youtu.be).

2)  After changing the ListItem property

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

I get better behaviour but something is still going on.  It simply seems like the items inside the list are not receiving the events, so that property change made sense to me.
[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikznIMVat-4&feature=youtu.be) of how the spinners behave after updating that property.
All works fine except when I actually select an item.

3) After setting the ListView's layout_height="match_parent" the problem seems to go away after selecting an item.  [See here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tz0aXHeMLyI&feature=youtu.be) for that video.

The Activity:

```
public class SelectorActivity extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = SelectorActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selector);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ListView contents = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);    
    contents.addHeaderView(new TestView(this));
    contents.addFooterView(new View(this));
    SimpleBaseAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleBaseAdapter(this);

    // LOW RANGE
    LinearLayout lowRange = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_edit, null);
    TextView lowRangeText = (TextView) lowRange.findViewById(R.id.text);
    EditText lowRangeEditText = (EditText) lowRange.findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
    // HIGH RANGE
    LinearLayout highRange = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_edit, null);
    TextView highRangeText = (TextView) highRange.findViewById(R.id.text);
    EditText highRangeEditText = (EditText) highRange.findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
    // UNITS
    LinearLayout units = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_units, null);
    TextView unitsText = (TextView) units.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

    // SPINNERS
    LinearLayout spinners = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_spinners, null);

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    DebugAdapterViewListeners.set(spinner1, "spinner1");

    // VIEW SETUP
    lowRangeText.setText("text1");
    highRangeText.setText("text2");
    unitsText.setText("text3");
    // SPINNER SETUP
    String[] massUnits1 = new String[]{"one","two"};
    String[] massUnits2 = new String[]{"three","four"};
    String[] timeUnits = new String[]{"five","six"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_list_item_centered);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_list_item_centered);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_list_item_centered);
    adapt1.addAll(massUnits1);
    adapt2.addAll(massUnits2);
    adapt3.addAll(timeUnits);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapt1);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapt2);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapt3);

    listAdapter.addView(lowRange);
    listAdapter.addView(highRange);
    listAdapter.addView(units);
    listAdapter.addView(spinners);

    contents.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.selector, menu);
    return false;
}


}
```

Here is the SimpleBaseAdapter class:

```
public class SimpleBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<View> views;
private Context context;

public SimpleBaseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.views = new ArrayList<View>();
}

public void addView(View view) {
    this.views.add(view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return views.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    View view = views.get(position);
    if (view instanceof AbsListView) {
        return ((AbsListView)view).getItemAtPosition(position);
    } else if (view instanceof AbsSpinner) {
        return ((AbsSpinner)view).getItemAtPosition(position);
    }  else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    View view = views.get(position);
    if (view instanceof AbsListView) {
        return ((AbsListView)view).getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    } else if (view instanceof AbsSpinner) {
        return ((AbsSpinner)view).getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    }  else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return views.get(position);
}

}
```

Activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green_1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"        
        android:dividerHeight="0.5sp"
        android:divider="@color/black"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="18sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18sp"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="@dimen/row_padding"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_standard"
      android:textColor="@drawable/selector_row_item_detail_text"
      />
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/edit"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="right"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The spinner row item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/header_row_padding_vertical"


        >
            <Spinner
              android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                />
            <Spinner
              android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                />
            <Spinner
              android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you were facing was the basic behaviour of Spinner, so a modified Spinner is needed. This is code for the spinner whose initial ie. by default the visualisation is "Select Item" (if the prompt declared in the .xml like `android:prompt="@string/Select Item"`) & the dropdown views are the same size of the original spinner. The limitation of this modified spinner is that it does not display the prompt if the items are empty.

Make a new class named `NoDefaultSpinner.java` & in  that copy paste this code

```
public class NoDefaultSpinner extends Spinner {

    public NoDefaultSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoDefaultSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NoDefaultSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter orig ) {
        final SpinnerAdapter adapter = newProxy(orig);

        super.setAdapter(adapter);

        try {
            final Method m = AdapterView.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                               "setNextSelectedPositionInt",int.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(this,-1);

            final Method n = AdapterView.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                               "setSelectedPositionInt",int.class);
            n.setAccessible(true);
            n.invoke(this,-1);
        } 
        catch( Exception e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected SpinnerAdapter newProxy(SpinnerAdapter obj) {
        return (SpinnerAdapter) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                obj.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                new Class[]{SpinnerAdapter.class},
                new SpinnerAdapterProxy(obj));
    }



    /**
     * Intercepts getView() to display the prompt if position < 0
     */
    protected class SpinnerAdapterProxy implements InvocationHandler {

        protected SpinnerAdapter obj;
        protected Method getView;


        protected SpinnerAdapterProxy(SpinnerAdapter obj) {
            this.obj = obj;
            try {
                this.getView = SpinnerAdapter.class.getMethod(
                                 "getView",int.class,View.class,ViewGroup.class);
            } 
            catch( Exception e ) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            try {
                return m.equals(getView) && 
                       (Integer)(args[0])<0 ? 
                         getView((Integer)args[0],(View)args[1],(ViewGroup)args[2]) : 
                         m.invoke(obj, args);
            } 
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw e.getTargetException();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        protected View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
          throws IllegalAccessException {

            if( position<0 ) {
                final TextView v = 
                  (TextView) ((LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,parent,false);
                v.setText(getPrompt());
                return v;
            }
            return obj.getView(position,convertView,parent);
        }
    }
}
```

In spinner row item layout change the type of spinner to `<com.example.appname.NoDefaultSpinner` like this

```
        <com.example.appname.NoDefaultSpinner
          android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            />
        <com.example.appname.NoDefaultSpinner
          android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            />
        <com.example.appname.NoDefaultSpinner
          android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            />
```

The Activity : Change the type of Spinner to NoDefaultSpinner like this

```
public class SelectorActivity extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = SelectorActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_selector);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

ListView contents = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);    
contents.addHeaderView(new TestView(this));
contents.addFooterView(new View(this));
SimpleBaseAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleBaseAdapter(this);

// LOW RANGE
LinearLayout lowRange = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_edit, null);
TextView lowRangeText = (TextView) lowRange.findViewById(R.id.text);
EditText lowRangeEditText = (EditText) lowRange.findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
// HIGH RANGE
LinearLayout highRange = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_edit, null);
TextView highRangeText = (TextView) highRange.findViewById(R.id.text);
EditText highRangeEditText = (EditText) highRange.findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
// UNITS
LinearLayout units = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_units, null);
TextView unitsText = (TextView) units.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

// SPINNERS
LinearLayout spinners = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_spinners, null);

NoDefaultSpinner spinner1 = (NoDefaultSpinner) spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
NoDefaultSpinner spinner2 = (NoDefaultSpinner) spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
NoDefaultSpinner spinner3 = (NoDefaultSpinner) spinners.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
DebugAdapterViewListeners.set(spinner1, "spinner1");

// VIEW SETUP
lowRangeText.setText("text1");
highRangeText.setText("text2");
unitsText.setText("text3");
// SPINNER SETUP
String[] massUnits1 = new String[]{"one","two"};
String[] massUnits2 = new String[]{"three","four"};
String[] timeUnits = new String[]{"five","six"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapt1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_list_item_centered);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_list_item_centered);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_list_item_centered);
adapt1.addAll(massUnits1);
adapt2.addAll(massUnits2);
adapt3.addAll(timeUnits);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapt1);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapt2);
spinner3.setAdapter(adapt3);

listAdapter.addView(lowRange);
listAdapter.addView(highRange);
listAdapter.addView(units);
listAdapter.addView(spinners);

contents.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.selector, menu);
return false;
}
```

This  solution relies on reflection to call the `AdapterView.setNextSelectedPositionInt()` and `AdapterView.setSelectedPositionInt()`, & runs successfully on API 4 to API 19.

Comment: Your solution seems to work, but I don't understand why it is necessary and what is causing the problem.  Could you explain further.

Comment: I agree. An explanation would be helpful before awarding the bounty. Could you please explain why this solution is working? Thanks!

Comment: You should accept the answer seeing as you've awarded the bounty, it closes the question to get it off the unanswered list

Answer (score 1):

You should extend SpinnerAdapter rather than BaseAdapter. It has getDropdownView() as well as getView() and i believe it handles some special cases internally itself. I am extending this adapter in a similar layout on android 4.2 and I don't see the issues you have.

I would hazzard a guess that a difference in how getDropdownView() handles attaching the view to the root would account for this difference but I haven't looked into the code to check this

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'll give that adapter a try and post the results.

Comment: This didn't work for me; What do you have in your impl for getDropdownView ?  Thanks.

Comment: I am at work now, when I go home I will share it with you, in the mean time maybe you could update your question with the spinner adapter instead of the base adapter?